# Error while running Update-Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I got the following error while running `Update-Database -Verbose`:

> Using StartUp project 'WebApplication'. Using NuGet project
>   'WebApplication'. Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL
>   statements being applied to the target database. Target database is:
>   'Frappuccino' (DataSource: (Localdb)\v11.0, Provider:
>   System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Configuration). No pending explicit
>   migrations. Applying automatic migration:
>   201402032027563_AutomaticMigration. ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Clients] ALTER
>   COLUMN [ID] [int] NOT NULL System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>   (0x80131904): The object 'PK_dbo.Clients' is dependent on column 'ID'.
>   The object 'FK_dbo.Users_dbo.Clients_Client_ID' is dependent on column
>   'ID'. ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN ID failed because one or more objects
>   access this column.    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String
>   methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TInterceptionContext,TResult](Func`1
>   operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`1
>   executing, Action`1 executed)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand
>   command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(DbTransaction
>   transaction, MigrationStatement migrationStatement)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ExecuteSql(DbTransaction
>   transaction, MigrationStatement migrationStatement)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements, DbConnection connection)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c_*DisplayClass32.b*_2e()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1
>   operation)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action
>   operation)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String
>   migrationId, XDocument targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations,
>   IEnumerable`1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.AutoMigrate(String
>   migrationId, XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, Boolean
>   downgrading)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.AutoMigrate(String
>   migrationId, XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, Boolean
>   downgrading)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1
>   pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1
>   pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String
>   targetMigration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c_*DisplayClassc.b*_b()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action
>   mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action
>   mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String
>   targetMigration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String
>   targetMigration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run() 
>   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate
>   callBackDelegate)    at
>   System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner
>   runner)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String
>   targetMigration, Boolean force)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c_*DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b*_0()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action
>   command) ClientConnectionId:9854ba62-772c-4ba6-b185-ecae993e065f The
>   object 'PK_dbo.Clients' is dependent on column 'ID'. The object
>   'FK_dbo.Users_dbo.Clients_Client_ID' is dependent on column 'ID'.
>   ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN ID failed because one or more objects access
>   this column.

What I did before this is to change the `ID` variables from my *Code-First Model* classes from `Int16` to `Int32`.

Any help please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like the database can't alter/drop the ID column because another table has a foreign key referencing the ID column.  If you drop the reference, update the column, and then re-add the reference, you should be good to go...

Comment: How do I recreate the database? I've deleted it to try what you said, and now I can't get it back.

Comment: You deleted the entire database? If so, when you run your application the database should be re-created by entity framework in the location you specify. I believe the default location is SQL Express.  What database are you using? How did you create the database before?

Comment: I've created using `Code-First`, so I haven't touch anything _database related_ **EDIT**: After running the application, the only table that was created was `_MigrationHistory`. Guess I had a bigger problem now.

Comment: **PROBLEM SOLVED**: After deleting all _migration related_ folders, files and tables, I re enable the `Migrations` and repopulated the database as you've said.

Comment: I also had this issue when there was a constraint on a column, the migration would fail because EntityFramework failed to drop the constraint on the column. To resolve this, I modified the migration script to drop the column before attempting to recreate it.

Comment: If you re-create migration files, you lost previously migration tracks. how could this be a solution if you are developing a serious commercial project?

Answer (score 7):

> PROBLEM SOLVED: After deleting all migration related folders, files and tables, I re enable the Migrations and repopulated the database as you've said

Building on the accepted answer, here are specific steps to work around the issue without dropping all migrations or manually editing one.

In my situation I had

```
public class Parent
{
    public virtual ICollection<Child> A { get; set; }
}
```

The type for the child had to be changed from Child to OtherChild.  That is when I encountered the error.

To work around it, I created two migrations.  The first simply unmapped the property A from EF.  I could have also commented it out, but quite a bit of code accessing the property would have failed to compile.

```
public class Parent
{
    [NotMapped]
    public virtual ICollection<Child> A { get; set; }
}
```

> add-migration UnmapA
>
> update-database

then I re-mapped the property and changed the type

```
public class Parent
{
    public virtual ICollection<OtherChild> A { get; set; }
}
```

> add-migration ChangeChildType
>
> update-database