# EntityFramework connection to SQL server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have exactly the same configuration in app.config files in two projects in different solutions.

One is an old solution where I deleted the old migrations, changed the DB and started getting connection errors with the new DB.

I reinstalled EF, deleted migrations, re-enabled them etc. Nothing works.

I created a new solution, installed EF, copied my model classes into it and tried the same. It works! The migration codes generated are exactly the same.

So the same configuration for the same code are in two different solutions on the same computer. One gets the below error while the other one works.

- Enable-Migrations -> works fine
- Add-Migration -> created migration files
- Update-Database -> gets the below error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing
>   a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not
>   accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

It's not the same error with the other question mentioned in the comments.  Different exceptions.

**Edit:** I copy the project files and add it to a brand new solution. And it works! I restarted the old solution, restarted my computer, reinstalled all packages in the project. Nothing works. I really need to make it work on that solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error while running Update-Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537447/error-while-running-update-database)

Comment: No it's not. It's a different error. In that question the user is getting an error in one of the queries during the migration. I get this error before the queries are executed during connection.

Comment: does the sql user has enough rigth for create a database for example ? Can you show us both app.config (connectionStrings section should be enough)

Comment: Yes it's the same connection string on both projects. The credentials are the same. That would cause an authorization failed error anyway.

Comment: can't be exactly the same or it will connect to the exact same database.

Comment: Yes that's the thing. I dropped everything on the DB and tried running migrations for the same code from a clean project. It worked. Dropped everything on the DB again, then tried running the migrations on the original project. It doesn't work.

Comment: There are a couple of similar questions on SO with answers suggesting the problem is related to which particular project is selected as the 'Startup Project' for the solution, at the time you run `Update-Database`...Seems easy enough to check it .  Such as this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26065864/error-when-updating-db-sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-serve

Comment: Thanks. I did not see that one in my search. The problem was the startup project. That's not mentioned in any EF connection problem debuging guides. Cost me a day. Thank you very much.